# SpringBoot Request form data with body and file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I'm having some trouble using an endpoint that uploads a file along with a string that serves as the request body.

In Springboot 2.7, I can easily use the following method and it works fine:

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<Object> upload(@RequestPart("fileRequest") String fileRequest, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    return pinataService.uploadFile(file, fileRequest);

}
```

[image]

But when I upgraded to Springboot 3.1, for some reason this doesn't work anymore and it doesn't recognize the file.

[image]

What could be happening?

Comment: Read the message !

Answer (score 0):

change the mediaType to `application/pdf` as your first file is a text file and the second is a PDF.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In fact, the problem is that for Springboot 3.0 FilePart is now used instead of MultipartFile, changing that started working without problem.